# Mod Rewrite based on HTTP_HOST don't change browser address

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd

I am not exactly clear on why this isn't working properly.  I have `sub.domain.com` with its contents in `/sub_folder`, and sub.domain.com is listed in the ServerAlias directive for `domain.com`.  The DNS for both point to the same IP.  In the vhost for domain.com I also have the following rewrite to send it to the right folder for the subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/sub_folder
```

This works, but I am being asked to make it so that the browser address does not change from `sub.domain.com` to `http://domain.com/sub_folder`.  I have tried changing to:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /sub_folder [L]
```

And also tried

```
RewriteRule (.*) /sub_folder [PT]
```

Both give errors.  I have tried adding the index.html on both which makes no difference in behavior (so I assume Directory Index takes care of it).  It looks like the first breaks some of the includes for the page, and the other causes a redirect loop.  Is the syntax correct for what I am trying to accomplish on either? RHEL 6 httpd 2.2.15

Answer (score 1):

I would make another Virtual Host in Apache for the `sub.domain.com` instead of the Rewrite hack. Much simpler and robust.

So, for the other Virtual Host entry, you enter the hostname `sub.domain.com` and put the document root to `sub_folder`.

And then you remove the `ServerAlias` entry.

Comment: This is probably a better solution, and I have thought of it already, but I still want to know the answer to my question in order to better understand mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment because reputation>50 is needed)

> Both give errors.

What errors? 404? 304? An error message in the logs?

Comment: I said one gives a redirect loop and the other breaks includes, the page displays incorrectly.

Comment: What are the includes exactly that the [L] flag break?